# Magento Extension to include more data in product information

Tags: api, magento, xml-rpc

Ok, here is my situation.

We are trying to import products from our customer's Magento Store into our application.

From all the standard api calls available to us using XML-RPC we have managed to get partial information.

But we were how ever not able to get the product URL. The reason for this is the catalog_product.list and catalog_product.info are not returning "product url" information about a product.

- Question 1)
  Is there a way to solve this problem with the existing standard Magento API?
- Question 2)
  If not, would it possible by providing extension through MagentoConnect to the customer and make "catalog_product.list" api respose to include "product url"

Note:

It's not only ful product url, we would like to include some more information to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.